# Problem of multiple definition in netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I have 2 files namely fun.cpp and main.cpp

**fun.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum()
{
    cout << "hello";
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "fun.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

sum();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code in netbeans, I get this output

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/adbms_v1.5
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/adbms_v1.5 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/fun.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o  
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `sum()':
/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5/fun.cpp:5: multiple definition of `sum()'
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/fun.o:/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5/fun.cpp:5: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/adbms_v1.5] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ravi/NetBeansProjects/ADBMS_v1.5'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 150ms)
```

Can anyone explain what the problem is??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Do not include cpp file which has function defintion in other cpp files.
This causes multiple function definitions of the same functions and breaks the **[One definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).**

Put the declaration of the function in an header file and then include that header file in whichever source file you want to use the function.

**fun.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_FUN_H
#define HEADER_FUN_H

void sum();

#endif //HEADER_FUN_H
```

**fun.cpp**

```
#include "fun.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void sum()
{
    cout << "hello";
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "fun.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    sum();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each `.cpp` file and all the files that the `.cpp` file includes is called *a translation unit*. The compiler compiles each translation unit separately. The linker then puts it all together into a single executable.

Before the compiler actually compiles the code, it executes all preprocessing statements first, for example, the `#include` statements in both your `.cpp` files. The `#include` statement simply takes the contents of the specified file and "copies" it into the file where the `#include` statement is. For example, `fun.cpp` may look like this after preprocessing:

```
/* the contents of the iostream file goes here */
using namespace std; 
void sum() 
{ 
    cout << "hello"; 
}
```

For `Main.cpp`, something like this:

```
/* the contents of the cstdlib file goes here */
/* the contents of the iostream file goes here */
using namespace std; 
void sum() 
{ 
    cout << "hello"; 
} 
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{  
    sum();  
    return 0;  
}
```

As you can see, the contents of `fun.cpp` has been "inserted" into `Main.cpp`. So now you have two definitions of `sum()`, which is a violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR) in C++. Since the compiler processes each translation unit separately, this error wasn't found until the linker saw that you have two different definitions, and rightly complained as a result.

Since the `sum()` function is quite simple, one way to solve the problem is to make the `sum()` function `inline`, rename the `fun.cpp` file into `fun.h`, and include `fun.h` into `Main.cpp` instead of `fun.cpp`.

```
// fun.h
#include <iostream>
inline void sum()
{
    std::cout << "hello";
}

// main.cpp
#include <cstdlib>         
#include <iostream>         
#include "fun.h" // Note "fun.h" 

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{         
    sum();
    return 0;
}
```

For bigger functions, or if you want to hide the implementation, [Als' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299225/problem-of-multiple-definition-in-netbeans/7299253#7299253) is more appropriate.